# How to compute $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{p^2}{2}}\,dp \int_{|x|< |t(p-p_o)|}\,dx\,?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Consider the integral:

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-p^2/2}\,dp \int_{|x|< |t(p-p_o)|},dx\,.$$

If I just intgerate the $x$ part I get $2t(p-p_0)$ in the integrand with the exponential but on the board it was calculated as:

$$I=t\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-p^2/2}|p-p_0|\,dp \,.$$

I am not sure if my calculation is the same as this one but I do not think so. I think a factor of $2$ will still be different in both these calculations.

Comment: Factor of $2$ has to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct when you say there is a missing 2. However, the absolute value must be kept (also for $t$ if nothing is said about its sign). So the integral would be
$$
I=2 |t| \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |p-p_0|e^{-\frac 12 p^2} \, dp.
$$

You can now split the integral on $p_0$ to get rid of the absolute value and compute using the standard normal distribution.

Comment: You exactly pin pointed my confusion. Though  I still don't understand why should the absolute value be kept? Is it because there is a |$x$| instead of $x$?

Comment: The integral with respect to $x$ is the integral of the function identically equal to 1, over the set $\{x: -|t(p-p_0)| \leq x \leq |t(p-p_0)|\}$. It is the length of this interval. And the length is $2|t(p-p_0)|$, where  the absolute value is really necessary.